# Using .find of Mongoose to get a list of all users and create an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to get a list of the users in my server but it doesn't work, the list is always empty.

That's my code:

```
function gettingRegion(){
   var listUsers = []
    User.find({},function(err, response){
            if(!err)
            {
                listUsers = response
            }
    })
    console.log(listUsers)
}
```

I tried Async, putting a return inside the `.find` and creating a function outside the `.find` but it didn't work. Can you help me ?